# Shell endlessly loops when EOF is entered C

Tags: c, shell, fgets, eof, getline

I am a new C programmer who is attempting to create their own shell. The shell itself works well and processes my commands correctly, but when the user enters the EOF character as input into the command line, my shell just infinite loops. My code is posted below as well as what I've already attempted (I'm also new to using GDB and Valgrind but neither is seeming to help me locate the issue).

**What I have tried already:**

1. The current implementation below attempts to capture the return value of getline and handle the case where it returns -1 (when EOF is read). However this just causes the shell to endlessly loop the prompt
2. I replaced my function call completely with:

   ```
   if (fgets(command_line, MAX_CANON, stdin) == NULL) {
     printf("\nTo quit, please use the exit command: exit.\n");
   }
   ```

To my knowledge the above replacement should handle an EOF character input by the user. However this implementation using fgets also causes an endless command prompt loop.

Below is my current implementation which is referred to in #1 above:

**Function called in main to read input from user:**

```
char *read_command_line(void)
{
    //Declare an integer to hold the length of the string, a line to hold our output, and a variable getline can use to hold the generated buffer
    int len;
    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t bufsize = 0;

    //Get the line from stdin 
    int retval = getline(&line, &bufsize, stdin);

    if(retval == -1)
    {
        line = NULL;
        return line;
    }

    //Determine the length of the line and set a null terminating byte to end the string and get rid of the trailing return
    len = strlen(line); 
    line[len - 1] = '\0';

    //Finally return the read in line
    return line;
}
```

**Beginning of my shell while loop where line is read in:**

```
//BEGIN SHELL
  while (go)
  {
    //Signals are handled in the main.c  
    //Print the prompt
    char cwd_loop[max_buf_size];
    getcwd(cwd_loop, sizeof(cwd_loop));
    printf("\n%s [%s]:> ", prompt_prefix, cwd_loop);

    commandline = read_command_line();  

    if(commandline == NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: `line[strlen(line) - 1]` seems a bit iffy. This operation should - by definition - not change anything.

Comment: @broman Good call, I seem to have forgotten that getline returns a string that is already null terminated. I'll remove this useless code. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, it's more than that. It's not only that it is useless. The `strlen` function will simply not work if the string is not terminated. What `strlen` does is to return the index of the first `\0` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code

```
commandline = read_command_line();  

if(commandline == NULL)
{
    continue;
}
```

If `read_command_line` returns a null pointer, which it does if there's an error like `EOF`, then you *continue* the loop, letting it iterate again. This time `read_command_line` will *again* return a null pointer, and you continue like that forever.

You should **`break`** out of the loop if `read_command_line` returns a null pointer.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes perfect sense. I've done that for now to prevent any future issues, but my main goal was to implement the handling in a way that allowed the shell to elegantly resume prompting the user without requiring them to run the program again. Hopefully I'll be able to work that out myself with some more research. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: That would be equivalent to writing a GUI tool that "elegantly" restarts itself every time you hit "File -> Quit" so as to not require the user to manually re-invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not continue to prompt and read further input when the input stream has been closed as indicated by `getline()` returning `-1` or `fgets()` returning `NULL`. Just break out of the loop as if an `exit` command had been entered.

Comment: Thank you, the input stream closing makes sense to me and I was not taking that into account in the above. Is it possible to reopen the input stream and then issue a continue in the while loop so that when EOF is entered by the user, we don't exit but instead just prompt again? I will look into reopening the closed input stream on my own now as well. Thanks again.